# Mint changes default route when eth0 comes back and breaks existing tcp connections

Tags: networking, ssh, linux-mint, openvpn

I have two interfaces on my laptop (eth0, wlan0). lets say I am moving away from desk and connecting to an internal network A using openvpn software which uses wlan0 as gateway. I then ssh to a few vms inside this network A. when I return back to my desk, the system detects eth0 is available and automatically changes default route. I then lose vpn connection and all the ssh sessions with the vms in network A.

on wlan0

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.147.76.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
```

when reestablished connection with eth0

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.148.93.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

how to solve this issue?

Comment: This seems overly complicated to me but would appear to be an option: http://natisbad.org/dyn-net/index.html